# Sencha touch native alert with 3 buttons is getting cut, in Android 5.0 and above (lollipop)

Tags: cordova, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2, sencha-touch-2.1, sencha-cmd

I am using sencha native alert as below:

```
Ext.device.Notification.show({
    title: "Title",
    message: "My message",
    buttons: ["First button text", "Second button text", "Third button text"],
    callback: function(button) {
         //button callback will go here
    }
});
```

But when I install the app on Android version >= 5.0 and check the alert, it is cutting on the 3rd button.

I have added requires: ['Ext.device.*'] in app.js and also install below cordova plugins in sencha native package:

```
org.apache.cordova.device
org.apache.cordova.dialogs
org.apache.cordova.vibration
```

The third button is not displaying.

Note: I am using sencha touch 2.3.1

Please suggest me what should I do or if am doing something wrong, please let me know.

Thanks

Comment: did you get any solution???

Comment: I didn't get any solution yet.